# Ocaml: match clause arrows and reference

Tags: ocaml

When looking through some code I spotted a match clause of the form:

```
| x::y::[] -> a_ref.contents <- []; [call_function x]
```

a_ref is a list ref.

Could someone describe what is going on? Specifically here: a_ref.contents <- []; [call_function x]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say `a_ref` is, in fact, a `list ref`. I.e., it's a reference to a list (not a list of refs).

So the trick here is that a ref in OCaml is secretly a record with a mutable field named `contents`. Sometimes it comes in handy to know this.

However, in this case you could say

```
a_ref := []
```

instead of

```
a_ref.contents <- []
```

And, in fact, you should say this as it's more idiomatic.

The rest is just saying that the final value is a list containing the result of `call_function x`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I did indeed mean list ref. Edited post. Thanks for the answer. Another question: What does the backarrow mean?

Comment: The `<-` symbol is used for assignment to a mutable record field, instance variable, array, or string. You might think it's an operator like `:=` but it's actually a keyword.